# Batch processing and preventing timeout in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

In my controller, I need to generate a very data-extensive report. I would need to access about 150-200 fields in my SQL Server database, do some calculations, generate a PDF and have it available for download.

Is there a "batch" process or similar concept in Laravel that would help me with this? I need these reports to be created ad-hoc whenever a user decides and ideally display a progress bar while the report is being generated.

Thanks for any help or advice

Comment: You'll want to look into [Queues](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queues). What this will do is run a server-intensive job in the background and not tie up your user's browser resources. You'll probably have to use some kind of websocket or AJAX-based long-polling process to determine the progress/completion of the job, but this will at least get you to where you won't see any server timeouts.

Comment: If you use Queues, you can't get the real trace of your process for progress bar, becuase this is going to response in the less time possible and run the process in backgroud.

Comment: @JoseRojas Uh, wrong. You can absolutely get pseudo real-time progress using Pub-Sub notifications. That's why I mentioned Websockets or long-polling. It's not trivial, but it's not complicated either. PHP isn't terribly well-suited to the task, but [Redis](http://redis.io/) and [Socket.io](http://socket.io/) are fairly commonplace for these kinds of interactions.

Comment: You can also look into [Session Upload Progress](http://php.net/manual/en/session.upload-progress.php). From what it looks like, it doesn't work with FastCGI but I haven't tested that myself.